# Date format for IAPI documentum query

Tags: documentum

I am updating my documentum object using IAPI.

Below is IAPI script to update date

```
set,c,090d903886353e5a,r_creation_date
'12/12/2020 12:00:00 AM'
save,c,090d903886353e5a
```

After executing scripts i am facing below issue

> API> SET> ... [DM_API_E_BADDATE]error:  "You have specified an invalid
>   date or an unrecognized date representation ''12/12/2020 12:00:00 AM''
>   based on format 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a'"

As you can see i have entered date as `12/12/2020 12:00:00 AM`, in my opinion it is in correct date format.

Please suggest on this.

Note: Earlier i have entered date as `12/12/2020 12:00:00` that time also i got issue.

Answer (score 2):

Remove quotes from the date and time and it will work:

```
API> set,c,090d903886353e5a,r_creation_date
SET> 12/12/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

You can also specify date format pattern:

```
API> set,c,0c0d900c80000107,r_creation_date,M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a
SET> 12/12/2020 12:00:00 AM
...
OK
API> save,c,0c0d900c80000107
...
OK
```

Comment: it'll probaby work on your systems, but on mine it doesn't work (client settings), with removing quotes, ofc.

Comment: @Miki Yes of of course, on your system you can have problem and then you should use the second option - with date format pattern, as I already wrote into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating with Date Time properties in Documentum depends on client settings. 
However you can override it via date time pattern.

For example

```
create,c,dm_document
set,c,l,object_name
Api test
set,c,l,a_effective_date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mi:ss
2019-04-11 12:24:09
set,c,l,title
script-generated
save,c,l


create,c,dm_document
set,c,l,object_name
Api test
set,c,l,a_effective_date,MM/dd/YYYY HH:mi:ss
04/11/2019 12:24:09
set,c,l,title
script-generated
save,c,l
```

will create objects with same `a_effective_date` value.

Comment: Thanks it worked but changes didn't committed after set i executed dump again but net set values were not there...

Comment: you're probably overlooking something, but that's for another question, not this